# Json, get info within another level

Tags: javascript, php, json, getjson

I have json code that comes out like:

```
{
    "player": [{
        "player_id": "1",
        "player_name": "Maxfly",
        "player_image": "res_573fc05f57c0e.png",
        "player_background_image": "images/player_backgrounds/581046687fd89.jpg",
        "player_info": "",
        "player_region": "North America",
        "player_teams": [{
            "id": "1",
            "team_name": "Test Team",
            "team_link": "test-team"
        }, {
            "id": "65",
            "team_name": "Test Team 2",
            "team_link": "test-team-2"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I've managed to get the player_id and player_name etc. My question is how to I just get the teams? I've tried the following:

```
$.getJSON("jsonlink", 
    function(data) {
        $.each(data.player.player_teams, function(i,player_team){

            var append_data = "<div class='item team_item'><div class='row'><div class='col col_img'><a href='/t/" + player_team.team_name + "' ></a></div></div></div>";

            $("#popin-container").append($('<div>' + append_data + '</div>').hide().fadeIn(800));
        });
    });
```

Trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Is my json object correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Your JSON seems to be valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `data.player.player_teams` is wrong, as `data.player` is an array, and not an object. You need to loop through it, or in simple way, you need to attach a `[0]` like this:

```
$.each(data.player[0].player_teams, function(i, player_team) {
```

Comment: Thank you sir! That did.

Comment: No problem. The tick button though? i don't see that anywhere.

Comment: @christopher.web Happens, when you don't read the [tour]. Have a look buddy. `:D`